# Get index of search in substitute expression

Tags: search, substitute

In a substitute command, is it possible to retrieve the 'index' of the search (i.e. for the `n`-th match, the index is `n`)?

I am looking to use this in this context: `:s/pattern/\=[SEARCH INDEX HERE]`.

I looked around in help `:search`, etc. but could not find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it (maybe not the simplest way), using a recent Vim8 feature: *closures* (*):

- In your `vimrc`, add the following (reusable) function - a function that returns a reference to another function, one that increments a counter:

  ```
  function! MakeSearchIndex()
      let counter = 0
      function! SearchIndex() closure
          let counter += 1
          return counter
      endfunction
      return funcref('SearchIndex')
  endfunction
  ```
- Before every new search in which you need a search index, call `MakeSearchIndex()` and use its result as your `\=[SEARCH INDEX]` replacement part:

  ```
  let SI=MakeSearchIndex()
  %s/pattern/\=SI()/gc
  ```

or (one liner):

```
    let SI=MakeSearchIndex()|%s/pattern/\=SI()/gc
```

Basically, using a closure, you "capture" a new variable `counter` (created and set to 0 by each call to `MakeSearchIndex`), by making it visible and modifiable *only* in the returned `funcref`. So, while being local to `MakeSearchIndex`, `counter`'s life is actually bound to that of the returned object.

---

(*) I guess this makes the answer ... *emacs flavoured* (LISP style) :)

---

The variation below works in exactly the same way, but also lets you create search index functions that receive an optional *increment* argument:

```
function! MakeSearchIndex()
    let counter = 0
    function! SearchIndex(...) closure
        if (a:0 > 0)
            let counter += a:1
        else
            let counter += 1
        endif
        return counter
    endfunction
    return funcref('SearchIndex')
endfunction
```

.. so that you could use for example `SI(3)` to increment the current counter with 3 at every call, or `SI()` (as before) to increment with 1.

(Well, I presume I just re-created the "counters" example from functional programming 101, or something like that :P)

Comment: Thanks, this is a clever application (with the small downside that SI() have to called in every replacement text, e.g., can't be called in an if branch that is sometimes not taken). I'll wait a bit more for other possible answers to flow in before accepting (I already upvoted but I won't show up until I have 15 rep.)