# Get index of search in substitute expression multiple times in Vim

Tags: vimscript, search-replace

Sorry. Although this is one duplicate question of [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/get-index-of-search-in-substitute-expression), but I don't have reputations now, so I can't comment on the above original question. As one workaround, I posted a new question and this is my first question in this vi community. Hope someone can help me.

My question: If I search multiple times in one file, the `counter` won't be reinited as `0` between each search (here `counter` is to index the searched items). So it will keep increasing if I do the same search twice which is obviously not what needed.

for example, for string `111`, if I searched first time and replaced, it is replaced as `123`, but if I search `222` in the same file without quiting vim, it will be replaced as `456`, which is not what I want( `123` to index them).

So can vim function reinited the counter referenced in the above link every time it gets called?

Specifically, I added one keymap based on above link

```
"from above link
function! MakeSearchIndex()
    let counter = 0
    function! SearchIndex() closure
        let counter += 1
        return counter
    endfunction
    return funcref('SearchIndex')
endfunction
let SI=MakeSearchIndex()
"my added keymap
cnoremap si s/\v/\=SI()/g<left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left>
```

Comment: It is easier for the reader if the question are self consistent. Maybe could you repeat the part of the question you are referencing and the answer you are using.

Comment: What `counter` are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks for the above quick answers, I updated and hoped you can understand my question and help me.

Comment: Welcome to vi and vim SE. Asking questions (and getting answers) is pretty much the whole point of this site, no need to apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reinitialize the counter to zero you have to run:

```
:let SI=MakeSearchIndex()
```

If you want to reinitialize the counter to zero at every search you could do:

```
cnoremap si let SI=MakeSearchIndex() <bar> s/\v/\=SI()/g<left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is same as the original link.

And since `|` may be misinterpreted (which I also met when following my reference link but at that time I didn‘t make a deeper try) according to [fandom](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Multiple_commands_at_once), this `cnoremap si s/\v /\=SI()/g <bar> let SI=MakeSearchIndex()<C-Left><C-Left><C-Left><C-Left><BS>` works

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!. I have updated the solution. If the solution fit your need maybe could you validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)